# Can't update from google play

Tags: android, google-play

In the last time when i'm trying to update my application from Google play, Google play avoid the update because I installed my app not from Google play, is there a solution how to update it anyway..?

Is it related to the new google play feature? "Let Google manage and protect your app signing key (recommended)"

Comment: You have to uninstall and install again that app. OR if you want update app, you must have installed previous signed version apk in your device.

Comment: I want to update my app from google play, without uninstall and install again, how can i do this? at least in my next versions

Comment: If you have installed previous version from Play store then only you can update it.

Answer (score 0):

From where you installed the app first? 
 a) Is it a build APK from Android Studio? Are you testing the app on your mobile device?
 b) Do you install the debug apk generated from Android Studio?
 c) Does the installed version has bigger Version code than the one on google play?

If a and b happens then You have to uninstall the app properly from your phone first. For that, you have to go to app info and then click on Right corner on the top and click Uninstall for all users(Mostly Android 6.0+)

If it option c then just uninstall the App and install the latest.

Remember One thing, App installed by Android Studio in the time of Testing is a debug apk, it is not signed. And App from playstore is signed. Two is not the same. That's why you can't update them.